# Substitute for 'is' with types of object known in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I'm trying to check if some `Type`is instance of another `Type`. Like in this simple method, the best option would be:

```
bool Example(Type instance, Type runtimeKnwownType) {
    return instance is runtimeKnwownType;
}
```

It is the best option because `is` works with interfaces, however it doesn't work with `Type` and not constant right operand. Another option is `Type.IsSubclassOf(object)` doesn't work with interfaces. So there is my question for substition of `is` in this scenario.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this?  I think this might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: if possible, can you give me a sample by code? what do you want to do exactly.

Comment: @maccettura I'm trying to create something like Binding in wpf, and want to chek whether source Property type and  consumer property type are possible to assign from source to consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment, you want to check the assignation of two types. Can you try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

`Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type c)`

> "True if c and the current Type represent the same type, or if the
>   current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the current
>   Type is an interface that c implements, or if c is a generic type
>   parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints of
>   c."

Answer (score 1):

You can `GetType` on both objects:

```
public Class1 abc;
public Class2 def;
public void Test()
{
    if (abc.GetType() == def.GetType())
    {

    }
}
```

Or

```
public bool Example(Type instance, Type runtimeKnwownType)
{
    return instance == runtimeKnwownType;
}
```

Comment: This wouldnt work for inheritance / derived types though

Comment: @maccettura very true, exact matches only. Other checks like `AssignableFrom`, etc. need to be handled differently.